# Can not re-sign Android system app without app crashing (using LineageOS)

Tags: android, crash, sign

I have re-signed all system apps of LineageOS with my own key and have replaced them all before the first boot. LineageOS boots normally but then all re-signed system apps crash with an error like:

```
SystemUI stopped, Settings stopped.
```

It seems that the re-signed system apps are unusable. Maybe I made some mistake or LineageOS has some anti-tampering check implemented?

What i have done:
I opened all system apps with the winrar zip manager and removed the CERT.RSA and CERT.SF files in each META INF folder and deleted all the names and SHA-256 digest entries in all MF manifest-files. Also all other apk for example, in the framework folder, like the framework-res.apk file, I edited them like this. Then I created a keystore with Key, using the Java keytool, I think this is self-signed. Then I signed all APKs with the Uber Apk signet tool and successfully performed zip-aligning. Then I flashed Lineage OS with TWRP on the phone. Before the first boot, I deleted the system apks with the TWRP file manager and replaced them with my self-signed ones. 
Uber-Sign-Tool: https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer

Picture of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsIv6.jpg

Thanks for your help

Mike the android-noob

Comment: I was confused from what position your apps "resigned", but then I understood :-) "Re-sign" is hopefully less confusing. Could you add the exact steps you used to sign the apps, and (if you didn't already) quote the error message exactly as it appears? That will help us to answer, and others to find the question later in a web search.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help i have edited the post i hope someone finds a solution i despair...

Comment: Also note that there is a site in the Stack Exchange network specifically for Android questions here: https://android.stackexchange.com . Use the same account and tag your question [lineageos](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lineageos) there and it should reach the right people :)

Comment: Good Idea i do it thx

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/can-not-re-sign-android-system-app-without-app-crashing-using-lineageos